# How to get the key of indexeddb to be use in put function

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I am trying to get the key of specific record in indexedDb to be updated. I searched all over the place including IDB's own documentation and have yet to find what I am looking for.

This here is my database ->
[IndexedDB records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUp7C.jpg)

What I am trying to do in the code below is to grab the keyPath 'id' value to be used to grab the specified record to be updated with the put function.

```
//Save page when choosen
var cv = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    let bits = cv.toDataURL("image/png");

    let ob = {
        created: new Date(),
        data: bits
    };

    let trans = db.transaction([currentNotebook], 'readwrite');

    let key = trans.objectStore(currentNotebook).get(getAllKeysRequest.result[currentPage]);

    let editReq = trans.objectStore(currentNotebook).put(ob, key);

    editReq.onerror = function (e) {
        console.log('error storing data');
        console.error(e);
    }
```

An error occur saying when the above code is being run

```
<font cUncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'put' on 'IDBObjectStore': The object store uses in-line keys and the key parameter was provided.
```

Answer (score 0):

So there are two things that seem like they might be giving you trouble.

1) Pertaining to your error of `Uncaught DOMException`, what the message means is that when you defined your object store you specified an `keyPath` of `id`, which means you are using inline keys for this store. This means that when you use the `.put()` method you cannot pass the key as the second parameter for that method, but you must put it inside the object you are trying to `put`. So, do `ob.id = key` and then just pass `ob` into the `put` call.

2) The way you get `key` might also be a problem. The `.get()` request is an asynchronous call, so there will be an `onsuccess` event fired when the `.get()` resolves. So you will want to have a handler to pull the key out of the successful get, and you will want to implement your `.put()` call inside that.

I've taken your code and modified it to reflect both changes I mentioned:

```
var cv = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
let bits = cv.toDataURL("image/png");

let ob = {
    created: new Date(),
    data: bits
};

let trans = db.transaction([currentNotebook], 'readwrite');

let key = trans.objectStore(currentNotebook).get(getAllKeysRequest.result[currentPage]);
key.onsuccess = function() {
    let _key = key.result;
    ob.id = _key;

    let editReq = trans.objectStore(currentNotebook).put(ob, key);
    editReq.onerror = function (e) {
        console.log('error storing data');
        console.error(e);
    }
}
```